# How to create a key map to open and close the quickfix window in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

If I use `:lopen`, Vim opens the quickfix window, and if I use `:lcl` on the window with errors (or the quickfix window itself), it closes it.

What I want to do in my `.vimrc` is to create a map that opens the quickfix like this:

```
nnoremap <F2> :lopen 10<CR>
```

but when I press <kbd>F2</kbd> again it closes it using `:lcl`.

Is there a way to know if the quickfix window is open and then execute the `:lcl`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In sufficiently new versions of vim (where `getwininfo` is available), try:

```
function! ToggleQuickFix()
    if empty(filter(getwininfo(), 'v:val.quickfix'))
        copen
    else
        cclose
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <F2> :call ToggleQuickFix()<cr>
```

Customizations,

- TO open the window in a vertical pane, `vertical copen`
- For the location list (instead of quick fix), replace `copen`/`cclose` with `lopen`/`lclose`, and `v:val.quickfix` with `v:val.loclist`.)

Comment: If you prefer a single line for conciseness, you can do `nnoremap <expr> <F2> empty(filter(getwininfo(), 'v:val.quickfix')) ? ':copen<CR>' : ':cclose<CR>'`

Answer (score 6):

There is a vim plugin: https://github.com/milkypostman/vim-togglelist

Comment: This does exactly what I need thanks. Still I wanted something a little simpler without the need of a plugin. +1 for the guidance, the script helped me create my own answer :)

Comment: The plugin has two functions. You can copy the code into you `vimrc`.

Comment: well that's true, still I don't get why it gets so complicated. Thanks for the quick answer btw!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it, probably skipping some gory details but it works:

```
function! ToggleQuickFix()
  if exists("g:qwindow")
    lclose
    unlet g:qwindow
  else
    try
      lopen 10
      let g:qwindow = 1
    catch 
      echo "No Errors found!"
    endtry
  endif
endfunction

nmap <script> <silent> <F2> :call ToggleQuickFix()<CR>
```

If there are no errors the lopen will not work so I try catch that, in case there is it opens the window and creates a variable. then if it doesn't it just closes it.

The cool thing is that this approach can be used to everything you would like to toggle.

Comment: As long as you just open the quickfix window through this mapping, that's fine. But keep in mind that your global state variable won't work when the quickfix window is opened through other means (autocmds, other plugins, etc.)

Comment: true, I would need to press F2 twice in that case. I guess there is a way to ask if the quickfix window is open, that would do the deal

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lua function to toggle the Quickfix list in neovim:

```lua
local function toggle_quickfix()
  local windows = vim.fn.getwininfo()
  for _, win in pairs(windows) do
    if win["quickfix"] == 1 then
      vim.cmd.cclose()
      return
    end
  end
  vim.cmd.copen()
end

km('n', '<Leader>qt', toggle_quickfix, { desc = "Toggle Quickfix Window" })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/liuchengxu/vim-clap/

and:

```
nnoremap <F2> :Clap loclist<CR>
```